# Graphql total results / pageinfo when searching with pagination

Tags: craft3, search, pagination, graphql

I'm trying to build something to search my data that is stored in Craft with graphql.
To make pagination work I want to know how many results there are in total.

I'm doing a query like this:

```
query($search: String, $relatedTo: [Int]) {
  entries(section: "address", search: $search, orderBy: "companyName", relatedTo: $relatedTo, limit: 10, offset: 0) {
    searchScore, 
    ... on address_address_Entry {
      sid,
      address_title,
    }
  }
}
```

*Truncated for readability*

I set a limit and an offset to see the first 10 results.
But i also need to know *the total amount* to determine how many pages there are

I've seen that there is a `_count` field of type `Int` on the `entryInterface` which says "Return a number of related elements for a field." But it seems to just give me the field's value itself, if I, for example, add it like this:

```
query($search: String, $relatedTo: [Int]) {
  entries(section: "address", search: $search, ... same) {
    _count:id,
  }
}
```

It just adds in the response `{"_count": "8154"}` (which is the id, so not very usefull)

I've looked at graphql docs:
https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

But it doesn't work to just add 'pageInfo' or 'totalCount', neither does the cursor stuff.

Any help to get this working is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `entryCount`. You can also add arguments to this, such as `section`: `entryCount(section:"news")`, for example.

Comment: Thanks, but:
There doesn't seem to be such option in what i'm trying. Can you elaborate how you've done this?
All i get is "cannot query "entryCount" on query" or "cannot query "entryCount" on type elementInterface"
Or i just don't know where to put the "entryCount", also possible!

Comment: Fastforward however much time has passed.
Looking back at graphql in the current version of Craft (3.5.8) and 'entryCount' works fully as expected. I haven't looked into the changelog, but I'm assuming it has been added somewheren between then and now! 
Marking your answer as accepted for if anybody is looking for it.